# MtxHotPlugService - virus or not?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I do see such process in task manager `MtxHotPlugService`.
How can I check if this is a virus?

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search would have revealed that this has something to do with `Matrox Graphics, Inc. GPU Chipset User Interface` and that it is most likely safe.

To determine whether it is a virus or not, perform a virus scan. You can also click properties on the process to find its path and then use a multi-virus scanner service like http://virusscan.jotti.org/en to test the file against multiple antivirus software.